# MongodbClient.connect() not working with mongodb locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb

- I am trying to connect to mongodb server locally at this ip `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/` yet still no connection to the mongodb server
- I have tried using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`  but not change .

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
const dbname = 'conFusion';
console.log("before connect");
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
    console.log('Connected SuccessFully');
});
```

- I have also run this command `Mongod --dbpath=data --bind-ip 127.0.0.1:27017` but no change
- Occasionally I would get the timeout error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: did you make sure the mongod process is actually running and listening on that port?

Comment: Mongod is running and listening on the port  there is no error message or sometime it shows timeout exception after 3000 ms